# How to make two network adapters work together seamlessly on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, routing

I have two network adapters installed on the same PC, one is wired and the other is wireless. Each of them is connected to internet through different router/AP and different ISP.

1. Is that possible to have them work together to boost my overall downstream/upstream bandwidth by combining them into one?
2. Is that possible to have certain application using one connection and others using another connection?

It's good to know if any hardware can achieve this, in the purpose of learning, but I currently don't intend to buy new hardware.

My system is Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, with a Realtek Gigabit Ethernet card (on-board) & TP-Link Wireless-N card.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is - probably not.

Slightly longer answer - maybe yes.

Multipath TCP and SCTP protocols where designed to address this issue, however they are not widely implemented. So until these become widespread a single application would not be able to use multiple links...unless the application itself is specifically designed to use two network interfaces, but most are not.

Another option is to bind different applications to different network interfaces. This can be done either by modifying the source code (if you have access to it, probably not) or by using utilities such as ForceBindIP.

Comment: http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/bridge-network-connections-in-windows-7/

Comment: @STTR The link you provided is using Windows 7's software bridge feature to bridge two different network. But what I'm seeking is combining two different internet connections...